# .saveas dont save at the current folder VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I Want to save a word document in a folder with a absolute path > 255 characters, but that doesn't work on vba. So I found a solution that I could change my current directory to this folder and then it should be possible to save the document in this folder.

So I did it this way

`ChDir newSavePath
 wrdDoc.SaveAs documentname`

the problem now is, that my word document get always saved in the Document folder of my homedirectory. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried: ChangeFileOpenDirectory "Path"     ?

Comment: You shouldn't try to get around the limit at all. [Link.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-office_install/unable-to-open-excelxls-files-with-very-long/290c6e39-929a-4788-95c4-d3364a7060f7)
A 260 character limit is immanent to Windows, Office programs have some variing shorter limits.

Comment: Sounds like it's the path/directory names that are too long. Can you not shorten them? Even if you resolve the problem, tomorrow another file will have the same problem.

Comment: Try `CurDir & documentName`

Comment: Try **`Application.DefaultFilePath = newSavePath`** then `wrdDoc.SaveAs documentname`

Comment: i couldnt shorten them, but i'm mapped the folder now to a drive to shorten the path, that works fine. ChangeFileOpenDirectory works also fine for paths smaller then 255, I test tomorrow at work, if it works for paths bigger then 255 too. Thanks for help :)